# How do I parse out multiple tags from Cost Explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm programatically trying to get the custom tags from Cost Explorer's API for my cost project. I'm using Boto3, Python3, SQL, and of course the Cost Explorer API. I have multiple custom tags that I would like to return, however, i'm (maybe?) only allowed to return one tag at a time. Here's my code:

```
    def get_tags(self):
        if self.args.range in self.date_range_mapping:
            response = self.ce.get_tags(
                TimePeriod={
                    "Start": self.date_range_mapping[self.args.range],
                    "End": self.today,
                },
                TagKey='custom_tag_1',
            )
        print(response)
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
TagKey='customt_tag_1','custom_tag_2','custom_tag_3', etc...
```

But i'm not sure if it's possible. I've tried using a list, but it only accepts strings.
Not sure where to go from here, and there aren't many examples online that I could find.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im having the exactly same question, from reading the API docs it seems you can pass only 1 tag

Comment: @TommyW I don't think it's possible.I ended up using Boto3's 'resourcegroupstaggingapi' to fetch that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should an [expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Expression.html) to add multiple tags to the api call. for example:

```
Filter : {
    And: [
        {
            Tags: {
                Key   : 'tag1',
                Values: ['value1']
            }
        },
        {
            Tags: {
                Key   : 'tag2',
                Values: ['value2']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```